# I'm trying to use a print.css to print one div per page, and I'm failing

Tags: css, printing, print-css

An example of my code is this:

```
<div class="print">
This div needs to be on one page.
</div>

<div class="print">
This div needs to print on a separate page.
</div>
```

I have a couple `divs` like above, and I need each `div` to be on it's own page when printed. I've tried `'page-break-before'` and `'page-break-after'` on the `.print` class in print.css. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

It seems to me like `'page-break-after'` would be right, and that's the solution I always find when searching, but I just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What's your CSS?  Because you need page-break-after: always, not just the attribute.  What browser?  Tested in multiple?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this after every `</div>` tag

```
<br clear="all" style="page-break-before:always" />
```

it works for me...

Comment: This worked except in Chrome. It seems like Chrome is the only one still giving me trouble. Nothing seems to work for it. @Sean the css is .print {page-break-after:always;} and that class is applied to multiple divs that need to be printed.

Comment: Safari is also giving me problems. It seems webkit has issues with page-break.

Answer (score 23):

You should use the css rule :

```
.print {page-break-after:always;}
```

It works for me in Chrome 12.0 and Firefox 3.5

The solution given by Allex using a br tag does not work in this version of Chrome

Comment: Tested on Chrome & Safari. Fantastic!